Water getting under edge of sink
I noticed a little evidence of water getting around the edge of my sink and I was thinking of adding clear caulk around the edge of the sink.  I can’t see that there was any ever applied there.  Would that help prevent more water leaking (in addition to wiping up any splashed water immediately in the future)?  Or do I need to remove the sink and reinstall using plumbers putty?
I’m new to home repairs so any advice would be appreciated
sink:

edge:

water damage:


Photo would help a lot. Caulking us usually applied under the sink rim if it drops in, on top of the sink rim if it attaches from below; either way ideally you don't see it without disassembling, and disassembling is the right way to recaulk... I think.

Fortunately, it looks like your mounting clips are easy—just unscrew with a flathead screwdriver.
